# Read count of parameter passed to user variable in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a requirement.

I am accepting an USER input in a variable using UNIX(ksh) script.

```
file_name='po_header*.dat ; po_line*.dat ; po_dist*.dat'
```

When I echo,

```
echo "Data File Names : " $file_name
```

I will get all the file names available at the location. The output will be like given below:

> po_headers_057.dat
>   po_headers_123.dat
>   po_headers_890.dat
>   po_lines_057.dat
>   po_lines_123.dat
>   po_lines_890.dat
>   po_distribution_057.dat
>   po_distribution_123.dat
>   po_distribution_890.dat

I need to get the count of file names passed to the variable separated with ';'. Here in this case **3**. i.e, **'po_header*.dat ; po_line*.dat ; po_dist*.dat'**

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In `ksh` without using any external utilities:

```
saveIFS=$IFS; IFS=';'; a=($file_name); IFS=$saveIFS; echo ${#a[@]}
```

As a bonus, your filespecs are now in an array:

```
$ echo ${a[1]}
po_line*.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

one way:

```
count=$(echo "$file_name" | awk -F';' '{print NF}')
echo $count
```

Edited - removed $NF -> NF

Comment: its giving me last 3 file names as given below. **`po_distribution_057.dat po_distribution_123.dat po_distribution_890.dat`**
I need the count as 3.

Comment: -F specifies the separator the character class or single character  that delimits a field for awk. The default is white space - tab and space characters.  Change the code above to match whatever you want. You originally gave ; as the field separator.  That is why awk -F';' is there.

Comment: you want `print NF` not `print $NF` -- NF is the number of fields; $NF is the last field's value

Answer (score 0):

```
count=`echo "po_header*.dat ; po_line*.dat ; po_dist*.dat" | \
sed 's/;//g' |wc -w|awk '{print $1;}'`
echo $count
```

works for `po_header*.dat ; po_line*.dat ; po_dist*.dat`, for `po_header*.dat ;; po_line*.dat ; po_dist*.dat;`, and for "po_header[0-9].dat ; po_line*.dat ; po_dist*.dat".

An alternative of `sed` is to use `tr ";" " "`.

Comment: When `wc` reads from stdin, it doesn't have a filename to print, so the pipe into awk is unnecessary. You can also just give awk the delimiter with `-F';'` as in @jim's answer

Comment: @glenn on my mac, `wc` prints `     3`, `awk` is to leave `3` only and works fine if the input is `3`.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't hurt to leave it there.  But it is useless.

Comment: @glenn It is useful if the `wc` is being used `conforms to IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'').` Ah, this thing doesn't display my comment correctly :) on my mac `wc` displays "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3" :)

Comment: Does that whitespace create a problem?

Comment: @glenn I don't know what it is going to be used for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
IFS=\; read -A a <<< "$file_name"; print ${#a[*]}
```

This sends the content of $file_name to the read command as its standard input, with IFS set to ; for the read (and only the read, so no need to save/reset it).  -A tells read to split the input on IFS and save each word in the named array (a).  ${#a[*]} gives the number of elements saved.